# Do I need to release a gesture recognizer?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, gesture-recognition, uigesturerecognizer

If I add a gesture recognizer to a table cell called `cell`, e.g.:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *_longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellGestureRecognized:)];
_longPressRecognizer.allowableMovement = 20;
_longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:_longPressRecognizer];
[_longPressRecognizer release], _longPressRecognizer = nil;
```

Do I need to manually call `-removeGestureRecognizer:` on this cell at some point, or does the gesture recognizer get removed and released for me when the cell is no longer used?

Comment: One thing to note is that target-action is not strong by default. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21578346/1418457

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The gesture recognizers are added to an internal NSMutableArray of the view. This array will be released once the view is deallocated. Thus `-removeGestureRecognizer:` doesn't need to be called manually.