# UIGestureRecognizer causes circular retain?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I was thinking, if you assign the target as `self` in the gesture recogniser's  `initWithTarget:action:` method, will you cause a circular retain? Since `self` will retain the recogniser in `self.gestureRecognizers` and it's possible the gesture recogniser to also retain self in `initWithTarget:action`.

Would the following be a solution for it?

```
__weak VRDrawer* weakSelf = self;
UIGestureRecognizer* tapRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:weakSelf
                                                                      action:@selector(handleTap:)];
```

Comment: What makes you think the gesture recognizer will retain the target? It should be pretty simple to print `[self retainCount]` before and after the code that allocates the gesture recognizer to see if it changes.

Comment: @GeoffHackworth: http://www.whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: @GeoffHackworth I don't know if it does retain the target of course, but since the docs mention nothing about it, one should wonder.

Comment: When one wonders, one tests. Use retainCount and see what happens! You get your answer and you remove the call to retainCount. It couldn't be more simple.

Comment: @GeoffHackworth you realise that the output from `retainCount` is not reliable right? You also know that you can't use it under ARC right? And `__weak` means I'm using ARC, in case you wonder...

Comment: @GeoffHackworth, belive me: the website is right — never use `retainCount` even not for printline-debugging.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I completely understand confirming something with the lack of documentation can feel unsettling. The important thing to note is that, by over a decade of convention, target-action relationships are never `strong`. Here's [the relevant docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Target-Action/Target-Action.html). Note the part that says:

> Control objects do not (and should not) retain their targets.

"Retain…" in the MRC way of saying "Holds a `strong` reference to…"

Given this is the documented convention for this type of interaction, it's safe to assume that, if `UIGestureRecognizer`'s target-action implementation *did* retain objects, that anomaly would be strange enough that it would show up in its docs.

---

P.S. You don't have to worry about the note that refers to controls retaining targets in memory-managed environments. "Memory-managed" refers to the (now depricated) garbage collection in Cocoa. Neither MRC or ARC is memory-managed.

Comment: Meanwhile, in other, not-too-distant worlds, for NSNoticationCenter it's the opposite: "You must invoke removeObserver: or removeObserver:name:object: before any object specified by addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: is deallocated." Which kind of explains why my removes in the `dealloc` method never work.

Answer (score 4):

```
UIGestureRecognizer* tapRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
```

This does not retain self. It would also be [noted in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279-CH1-SW1)

You need to add a recognizer to a view. That view will retain the recognizer. no retain cycle.

```
[aView addGestureRecognizer:tapRec];
```

[`addGestureRecognizer:` docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW103) do mention, that the view retains the recognizer

---

as you are using ARC, this is all you have to do

```
UIGestureRecognizer* tapRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[aView addGestureRecognizer:tapRec];
```

Comment: Where on that page did you find the info? It's not under `addTarget:action:` for sure.

Comment: the absence of the info is the info. there is no technical need to retail self in the recognizer.

Comment: @Meda, if the recognizer would retain the target, it would be in the docs.