# Is it recommended to remove gesture recogniser manually in iOS apps

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I found mixed answer to this question whether we should manually remove the gesture recogniser or not. Can anyone provide the better understanding on this?

This says **Yes**: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16970/gesturerecognizer-should-manually-remove

This says **No**:[Do I need to release a gesture recognizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274777/do-i-need-to-release-a-gesture-recognizer)

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are NOT talking about using Xamarin then:

No you don't, the answer on the second link you posted is right. The first link is talking about Xamarin, same rules don't apply.

This is how you attach a gesture recognizer.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622496-addgesturerecognizer

Under the "Discussion" part you can see this statement:

> The view establishes a strong reference to the gesture recognizer.

Whenever you see this kind of statements it can be implied that "This object will keep my added object alive since it will strongly reference it". Thus, once the object disappears my added object will go with it.

Comment: Thanks but just for my curiosity, still as a safe side I can add code to remove gesture recogniser correct or when its recommended to call remove api?

Comment: The remove method is usually only called when you are no longer interested in receiving gestures in that specific view. As you can see, the method is part of the UIView class itself, so If you were to call the method when your View is already deallocated you might run into a crash depending how you are doing this. So I would advice not removing it yourself.